# Quarzt.NET cron like configuration

Tags: quartz.net

It is unclear from manual http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html how to configure Quarzt.NET to execute some task every third day at 3pm starting from now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods available in CronScheduleBuilder are Daily, Weekly and Monthly so in order to execute your job with an special logic you should provide the trigger with Cron expression.
Use this website to build you own expressions: http://www.cronmaker.com/

In your case:

```
var myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 15 1/3 * ? *")
                    .Build();
```

If you want to start the job right now you can use:

```
var myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 15 1/3 * ? *")
                    .Build();
```

Moreover, you can specify your time zone in order to deal with daylight saving time issues in CronTrigger:

```
var myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 15 1/3 * ? *", x => x
                            .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time")))
                    .Build();
```

Comment: It is awesome answer, man!!! I didn't know about  this website. Thank you!